# React.JS / Next.JS NextAuth `useSession()` latency causes page load with the wrong user session info

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, session-state, next-auth

I am using `next 14.0.3`, `react 18.2.0`. A page in the application will call different backend service endpoints based on the presence / absence of user session object (whether the user is authenticated). However, there is a small window where the session is undefined during page refresh `F5` due to the latency of `useSession()` from `next-auth`. This will cause wrong information displayed when the page is ready. Even when using `useEffect` to track changes in `session` object it would call the service endpoint twice and will have performance impact.

```
const { data: session, update } = useSession()

  const getProductsByBrand = async () => {
    const request = new GetProductsRequest()
    request.setBrandid((brandId as string) || '')
    const pageReq = new PageRequest()
    pageReq.setPage(page - 1)
    pageReq.setPagesize(pageSize)
    request.setPaging(pageReq)
    request.setLocale(router.locale || '')
    if (session?.user?.id) 
        request.setUserid(session!.user.id)
    const res = session?.user?.id ? 
    await ProductService.getProducts(request, getMetaData(session?.user?.accessToken)) : 
    await ProductService.getProductsPublic(request, {})
    if (res.getProductsList()?.length > 0) {
// show data
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    getProducts()
  }, [brandId])
```

How best to tackle this issue?

Comment: Why can't you implement useEffect to wait for the session to update, and upon session update set a variable to ensure that the endpoint doesn't get called again... Isn't that simple enough?